# Limit $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0^+} z \int_1^\infty x^2 e^{-zx^2-zx} \mathrm dx $

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

Consider the following limit:
$$\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0^+} z \int_1^\infty x^2 e^{-zx^2-zx} dx $$
Can we find the answer to this limit without  calculating the integral?

I'll be thankful if you help me on this issue?

Comment: The limit is undefined.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Could you please tell me why the limit is undefined?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I corrected the limit. Could you please look at that once again?

Comment: The limit in this case is $\infty$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal why? Is this obvious?

Comment: No, it is not obvious.

Comment: For small $z$, the integrand is suppressed by the exponential factor unless $x^2 < \frac{1}{z}$. So a hand waving estimation of the order of expression is $z \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}} x^2 dx \sim O(\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}})$ as $z \to 0$.

Comment: @Mamal: Where did this limit come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see it diverges if you change variables to $y= \sqrt{z} (x + \frac{1}{2})$, the limit you want becomes:

$$
\lim_{z\to 0^+} ze^{z/4}\int_{3z/2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{z}}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 e^{-y^2} \frac{dy}{\sqrt{z}}
$$
The problematic term is the one containing $y^2$ expanding the polynomial, because this has an overall $\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}$, all other things give finite numbers in the limit, bu this factor makes the whole thing diverge.